# some includes are broken after antlr4 c++ runtime setup on linux

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, cmake, antlr4

I downloaded the antlr4 tool on linux and installed the c++ runtime to `/usr/local/include` , I created a small grammer file generated the parser and lexer with antlr4 command successfully but when compiling the main file the following error appears:

[image]

I changed the header of Interval.h inside `/usr/local/include/antlr4-runtime/misc/` and changed the include to relative path to work but other files also give the same error "antlr4-common.h: no such file of directory"

note that i followed the official steps to setup the c++ runtime but changed the last step to "`make install`" without `DISTDIR` just to setup it up to `/usr/local/include`

here my main cpp file and headers included
[image]

any ideas ?

Comment: You don't need to change the runtime headers, but instead add the include path of the runtime in your own app. That's all what should be necessary.

Comment: i already did and the same error still occur @MikeLischke am i doing it wrong ?

Comment: You should have an **include search** path `/usr/local/include/antlr4-runtime`. All paths in the runtime are relative to this path.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @MikeLischke Same problem here. I am setting up antlr in multi-module project. How should I provide this path? The setup for single module project does not need to provide `include search` path. Is there any example project for multi-module setup?

Comment: Also, I dont see this path or file on my ubuntu server:
`/usr/local/include/antlr4-runtime`. `antlr4-common.h` is in `cmake-build-debug/antlr4_runtime/src/antlr4_runtime/runtime/Cpp/runtime/src/antlr4-runtime.h`
@MikeLischke