# CMake Error : file INSTALL cannot set permissions on "/usr/local/include": Operation not permitted

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cmake, makefile, antlr4

I'm trying to run a transpiler project that converts alfa code to a solidity smart contracts, but after i run the final command **`make`** in order to generate an executable that'll convert the alfa to solidity, i get the following error:

```
CMake Error at _deps/googletest-build/googlemock/cmake_install.cmake:46 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot set permissions on "/usr/local/include": Operation not
  permitted.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  _deps/googletest-build/cmake_install.cmake:47 (include)
  runtime/cmake_install.cmake:47 (include)
  cmake_install.cmake:47 (include)
```

although i have set the permissions on /usr/local/include to 777, i still get the error after running the command.

I tried running **`sudo make`** instead of **`make`** but then i get other errors related to the antlr4-runtime library, which is this, but it has no answers : [some includes are broken after antlr4 c++ runtime setup on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52938604/some-includes-are-broken-after-antlr4-c-runtime-setup-on-linux).

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

here is the full trace of the error:

```
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target antlr4_tests
make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/new/transpiler/build6/antlr4cpp-prefix/src/antlr4cpp-build'
make  -f runtime/CMakeFiles/antlr4_tests.dir/build.make runtime/CMakeFiles/antlr4_tests.dir/build
make[5]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/new/transpiler/build6/antlr4cpp-prefix/src/antlr4cpp-build'
make[5]: Nothing to be done for '_deps/googletest-build/googlemock/CMakeFiles/gmock_main.dir/build'.
make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/new/transpiler/build6/antlr4cpp-prefix/src/antlr4cpp-build'
make[5]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/new/transpiler/build6/antlr4cpp-prefix/src/antlr4cpp-build'
make[5]: Nothing to be done for 'runtime/CMakeFiles/antlr4_tests.dir/build'.
make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/new/transpiler/build6/antlr4cpp-prefix/src/antlr4cpp-build'
[ 99%] Built target gmock_main
[100%] Built target antlr4_tests
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/new/transpiler/build6/antlr4cpp-prefix/src/antlr4cpp-build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/ubuntu/new/transpiler/build6/antlr4cpp-prefix/src/antlr4cpp-build/CMakeFiles 0
make  -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 preinstall
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/new/transpiler/build6/antlr4cpp-prefix/src/antlr4cpp-build'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for 'preinstall'.
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/new/transpiler/build6/antlr4cpp-prefix/src/antlr4cpp-build'
Install the project...
/usr/bin/cmake -P cmake_install.cmake
-- Install configuration: "Release"
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include
CMake Error at _deps/googletest-build/googlemock/cmake_install.cmake:46 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot set permissions on "/usr/local/include": Operation not
  permitted.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  _deps/googletest-build/cmake_install.cmake:47 (include)
  runtime/cmake_install.cmake:47 (include)
  cmake_install.cmake:47 (include)


make[3]: *** [Makefile:130: install] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/new/transpiler/build6/antlr4cpp-prefix/src/antlr4cpp-build'
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/antlr4cpp.dir/build.make:102: antlr4cpp-prefix/src/antlr4cpp-stamp/antlr4cpp-install] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/new/transpiler/build6'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:86: CMakeFiles/antlr4cpp.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/new/transpiler/build6'
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that it wants to set the permissions of `/usr/local/include` itself, not add content to `/usr/local/include`.  It doesn't matter what permissions you've given, only the owner of a file (or directory) can change the permissions of that file (or directory).

Comment: is there anyway to allow it to set the permissions ? any fix ?

Comment: There is no way to allow a user (that is not root) to change the permissions on a file that is owned by another user.  That's a fundamental basis of the POSIX security model (such as it is).  Your options are to either use `sudo` or similar to be root, or stop trying to do that.  I vote for the latter.  If your question is how to stop doing that, then you should contact the GTest devs and/or check their documentation, or read the CMake files that you're including.  I'm sure there's a way to prevent the install script from trying to change permissions on the installation directory.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue when I tried to install the CMake project that utilizes **GoogleTest** library. The library has a check whether to install its binaries or not. See [here](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/googletest/CMakeLists.txt#L90).

It looks like that when **antlr4-runtime** is installed by the GNU make it triggeres the installtion of the **GoogleTest**, however this is not required in your case. You have the following options:

1. For anyone facing this issue with CMake projects can find two workarounds in this [github issue](https://github.com/google/googletest/issues/3486)

   - add `option(INSTALL_GTEST OFF)` before `FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)`
   - if `add_subdirectory(googletest)` is used instead, pass `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` to prevent installation.
2. Propagate the `INSTALL_GTEST=OFF` to the CMake using the `-D` option. `cmake -DINSTALL_GTEST=OFF`