# fatal error: antlr4-runtime.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile, runtime, antlr

i'm trying to build a project with antlr4, once i run the command **`sudo make`** to start building the project, i get the following error:

```
/home/ubuntu/new/transpiler/main.cpp:2:10: fatal error: antlr4-runtime.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <antlr4-runtime.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/AlfaToSol.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/AlfaToSol.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:139: CMakeFiles/AlfaToSol.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

i've found the following question in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52938604/some-includes-are-broken-after-antlr4-c-runtime-setup-on-linux) but with no answers.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Here is the ExternalAntlr4Cpp.cmake where I included the antlr4 runtime that I have already built separately.

```
 set(ANTLR4CPP_JAR_LOCATION /usr/local/lib/antlr-4.7.1-complete.jar)

CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8.12.2)
PROJECT(antlr4cpp_fetcher CXX)
INCLUDE(ExternalProject)
FIND_PACKAGE(Git REQUIRED)

# only JRE required
FIND_PACKAGE(Java COMPONENTS Runtime REQUIRED)

############ Download and Generate runtime #################
#set(ANTLR4CPP_EXTERNAL_ROOT ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/externals/antlr4cpp)

set(ANTLR4CPP_EXTERNAL_ROOT home/ubuntu/Desktop/antlr4/runtime/Cpp/antlr4cpp)

if(NOT EXISTS "${ANTLR4CPP_JAR_LOCATION}")
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Unable to find antlr tool. ANTLR4CPP_JAR_LOCATION:${ANTLR4CPP_JAR_LOCATION}")
endif()

# default path for source files
if (NOT ANTLR4CPP_GENERATED_SRC_DIR)
  set(ANTLR4CPP_GENERATED_SRC_DIR ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/antlr4cpp_generated_src)
endif()

ExternalProject_ADD(
  #--External-project-name------
  antlr4cpp
  #--Depend-on-antrl-tool-----------
  # DEPENDS antlrtool
  #--Core-directories-----------
  PREFIX            
  SOURCE_DIR        /home/ubuntu/Desktop/antlr4/runtime/Cpp/
)

ExternalProject_Get_Property(antlr4cpp SOURCE_DIR)

list(APPEND ANTLR4CPP_INCLUDE_DIRS ${INSTALL_DIR}/include/antlr4-runtime)
foreach(src_path misc atn dfa tree support)
  list(APPEND ANTLR4CPP_INCLUDE_DIRS ${INSTALL_DIR}/include/antlr4-runtime/${src_path})
endforeach(src_path)

set(ANTLR4CPP_LIBS "${INSTALL_DIR}/lib")

macro(antlr4cpp_process_grammar
    antlr4cpp_project
    antlr4cpp_project_namespace
    antlr4cpp_grammar_lexer
    antlr4cpp_grammar_parser)

  if(EXISTS "${ANTLR4CPP_JAR_LOCATION}")
    message(STATUS "Found antlr tool: ${ANTLR4CPP_JAR_LOCATION}")
  else()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Unable to find antlr tool. ANTLR4CPP_JAR_LOCATION:${ANTLR4CPP_JAR_LOCATION}")
  endif()

  add_custom_target("antlr4cpp_generation_${antlr4cpp_project_namespace}"
    COMMAND
    ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory ${ANTLR4CPP_GENERATED_SRC_DIR}
    COMMAND
    "${Java_JAVA_EXECUTABLE}" -jar "${ANTLR4CPP_JAR_LOCATION}" -Werror -Dlanguage=Cpp -listener -visitor -o "${ANTLR4CPP_GENERATED_SRC_DIR}/${antlr4cpp_project_namespace}" -package ${antlr4cpp_project_namespace} "${antlr4cpp_grammar_lexer}" "${antlr4cpp_grammar_parser}"
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}"
    DEPENDS "${antlr4cpp_grammar_lexer}" "${antlr4cpp_grammar_parser}"
    )

  # Find all the input files
  FILE(GLOB generated_files ${ANTLR4CPP_GENERATED_SRC_DIR}/${antlr4cpp_project_namespace}/*.cpp)

  # export generated cpp files into list
  foreach(generated_file ${generated_files})
    list(APPEND antlr4cpp_src_files_${antlr4cpp_project_namespace} ${generated_file})
    if (NOT CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "MSVC")
    set_source_files_properties(
      ${generated_file}
      PROPERTIES
      COMPILE_FLAGS -Wno-overloaded-virtual
      )
    endif ()
  endforeach(generated_file)
  message(STATUS "Antlr4Cpp  ${antlr4cpp_project_namespace} Generated: ${generated_files}")

  # export generated include directory
  set(antlr4cpp_include_dirs_${antlr4cpp_project_namespace} ${ANTLR4CPP_GENERATED_SRC_DIR}/${antlr4cpp_project_namespace})
  message(STATUS "Antlr4Cpp ${antlr4cpp_project_namespace} include: ${ANTLR4CPP_GENERATED_SRC_DIR}/${antlr4cpp_project_namespace}")

endmacro()
```

Here is what the **/home/ubuntu/Desktop/antlr4/runtime/Cpp/** looks like:
[image]

Here is what the **/home/ubuntu/Desktop/antlr4/runtime/Cpp/antlr4cpp** looks like:
[image]

Comment: You probably have not set the right include path for the C++ runtime. I assume here you have downloaded or built the C++ runtime already.

Comment: @MikeLischke Hi mike, yes you're correct, I've pre-built the antlr4 runtime, it is located in ```/usr/local/include/antlr4-runtime```.  I've added this path to **include search paths** , but it still gives the same errors, any idea why ? thank you